# Layout elements weight problems

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to create xml for my ListView element. 
Here is my *.xml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactLastName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactPhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Every cell will have different value, and below is the picture of what I get, and what I'm trying to do:

[layout.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3IOi.png)

Almost sure that solution is to use android:weight, but I have already try almost everything... I'll appreciate any help or hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want to achieve

[image: Sample Image]

XML-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello2"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactPhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Sample text 1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Sample text 2"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your linear layout needs to have the weightSum attribute of 100. Then the other elements for example 30 30 40 to achieve what youre looking for.

Comment: and also layout_width to 0dp

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TEST NAME"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactLastName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TEST LAST NAME"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactPhone"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="0000000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactEmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/contactPhone"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="test@gmail.com"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```